# C# WPF рисование круговых и столбчатых диаграмм

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно реализовать построение диаграмм, исходя из данных, которые находятся в массиве(массив чисел).
В какую сторону нужно рыть?
Желательно это все должно рисоваться(возможно на Canvas'е)
Юзаю WPF.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему не вручную? Дел-то на копейку. Для круговых диаграмм, рассчитываем список углов:

```
var sum = data.Sum();
var angles = data.Select(d => d * 2.0 * Math.PI / sum);
```

Определяем радиус:

```
var radius = 100.0;
```

Теперь код пишется более-менее тривиально:

```
var startAngle = 0.0;

var centerPoint = new Point(radius, radius);
var xyradius = new Size(radius, radius);

foreach (var angle in angles)
{
    var endAngle = startAngle + angle;

    var startPoint = centerPoint;
    startPoint.Offset(radius * Math.Cos(startAngle), radius * Math.Sin(startAngle));

    var endPoint = centerPoint;
    endPoint.Offset(radius * Math.Cos(endAngle), radius * Math.Sin(endAngle));

    var angleDeg = angle * 180.0 / Math.PI;

    Path p = new Path()
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        Fill = Brushes.Red,
        Data = new PathGeometry(
            new PathFigure[]
            {
                new PathFigure(
                    centerPoint,
                    new PathSegment[]
                    {
                        new LineSegment(startPoint, isStroked: true),
                        new ArcSegment(endPoint, xyradius,
                                       angleDeg, angleDeg > 180,
                                       SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked: true)
                    },
                    closed: true)
            })
    };
    container.Children.Add(p);

    startAngle = endAngle;
}
```

Результат:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вручную много сил уйдёт на поддержку и отлов ошибок, если таковые будут. Да и вдруг потребуется добавить легенду или ещё что-то. Проще воспользоваться готовым компонентом из .NET.

Comment: @velikodniy: Ну, где ж ошибки? Задача-то тривиальная по сути, негде ошибаться. Плюс кастомизация: а если вы захотите свои цвета? Или свою толщину/стиль линий? Да и нет в WPF готовых компонент на все случаи жизни.

Comment: На все случаи, конечно, нет. Но если есть готовое, почему бы не воспользоваться? :)

Comment: @Андрей: Со столбчатыми диаграммами проблем быть не должно, они ж ещё проще. Просто вместо сегментов у вас прямоугольники. Ширина постоянная, высота пропорциональна значению.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный компонент `Chart` (из пространства имён `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`) позволяет строить различные виды графиков, в том числе и эти. Для его использования подключите сборку `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`. Но это компонент WinForms, а значит придётся использовать `WindowsFormsHost`.

Разобраться с компонентом достаточно легко, используя редактор свойств Visual Studio. Сами данные хранятся в коллекции Series (точнее, коллекции коллекций).

К сожалению, по какой-то причине в топе выдач поисковых систем этот компонент почти не упоминается, хотя он довольно мощный и может решить большинство типовых задач.

Если же возможностей компонента не хватает, то есть довольно много сторонних решений, но они часто платные и потребуют установки дополнительной сборки. Либо, как уже писали, можно отрисовывать диаграмму самостоятельно.

[Документация по классу компонента](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx)

Comment: Это WinForms, а не WPF.

Comment: Кстати, да, вы правы. Сейчас исправлю. Впрочем, это не мешает им пользоваться и в приложениях на основе WPF.